# Seeking alternative for ERDAS IMAGINE AutoSync?

Tags: software-recommendations, photogrammetry, map-matching, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I had the possibility to work with a Demo-Version of the ERDAS IMAGINE module AutoSync. 
I have different geo-rasters (i.e. geoTIFFs) produced by UAV photography and which have to be matched the best way possible in order to carry out some analysis. If possible, even inner distortions should be corrected in order to match the reference raster.

The AutoSync module above does the trick, but as a small startup company, we are not able to pay the prices the company asks for the license.

Consequently, I am searching for an alternative to this software.

Do you know a good alternative?

Ideally it would be open source, but even a proprietary software would be OK, if the price is accessible.

Answer (score 1):

if your UAV images are well overlapping (at least 3 images for each observed feature), I recommend [Agisoft Photoscan](http://www.agisoft.ru/products/photoscan). It is not free but not very expensive.

You can also have a look at orfeo toolbox, but it is not as easy to use as Erdas. However, they do have some tools for residual registration http://orfeo-toolbox.org/

Comment: Hello, in fact I'm working with Agisoft, a wonderful software for a relatively low price (almost an order of magnitude lower than similar products).

It is also possible to match the 3D models created with Agisoft within the software. The approach is based on matching the point clouds, delivering quite good results, but not as good as when matching RGB oder DEM data. A very small shift between the maps remains, which I want to avoid for my analysis.

In fact, the AutoSync module for ERDAS IMAGINE did the work very well, BUT demo time is out and the license tooo expensive.

Comment: And again hello radouxju. I'm was already experimenting with orfeo, but I do not get it to work. Not using Monteverdi2, not within QGIS 2.0. Should you know some tutorial showing exactly how to use Orfeo for the job I'm trying to do, that would be perfect.

Comment: Another software I just found, which looks (or better looked) promising, is [AutoGR 3.0](http://www.ims.forth.gr/index_main.php?c=90&l=e&d=7). Unfortunately I'm also having problems with it, since it does not seem to be able to manage my data.

Comment: A last possible solution for my problem would be [this correlator for gdal](http://correlatorgsoc2012.blogspot.de/), but also here, I do not find enough documentation to know how to use it.